# High-quality open-source street view panoramas

Tags: geospatial, images

We need ~1000 high-quality panorama street view images with location that can be downloaded and used as part of an open-source project. The ideal dataset would be [Google Street View Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/overview), but their API severely limits its use and our project does not fulfil [the restrictions](https://about.google/brand-resource-center/products-and-services/geo-guidelines/).

[Mapillary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapillary) and [KartaView](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KartaView) (formerly OpenStreetCam) both have 360-degrees panorama images licensed using [CC BY-SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license), which is great for open-source projects. However, the images are of very varying quality and many of them would not be suitable for our project due to being very dark, low resolution or not having full 360 degrees view.

Is there any such open-source dataset available or has anyone devised a way to filter Mapillary/KartaView to curate the high-quality images?

Comment: Originally posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/450826/high-quality-open-source-street-view-panoramas and was suggested to post here as well after not receiving any answers there.

Answer (score 2):

That won't cover the 1000 pictures requirement, but Wikimedia Commons has about 250 pictures that both:

- Are in the category https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:360%C2%B0_panoramas
- Have received a seal of approval for being of good quality.

Here is the link to see them: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:360%C2%B0_panoramas?fastcci=%7B%22c1%22%3A17392673%2C%22d1%22%3A15%2C%22s%22%3A200%2C%22a%22%3A%22fqv%22%7D

Many of them are not pictures of streets, unfortunately. You can cross with the "Streets" category but that takes time:

[image]

[PetScan](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?project=wikimedia&sitelinks_no=&format=html&ores_type=any&language=commons&ores_prediction=any&langs_labels_yes=&interface_language=en&since_rev0=&ns%5B0%5D=1&search_wiki=&smaller=&wikidata_prop_item_use=&edits%5Bbots%5D=both&outlinks_no=&sortorder=ascending&manual_list=&depth=10&output_limit=&links_to_all=&templates_no=&outlinks_yes=&labels_no=&sitelinks_any=&langs_labels_no=&sortby=none&cb_labels_any_l=1&cb_labels_yes_l=1&edits%5Bflagged%5D=both&show_disambiguation_pages=both&sitelinks_yes=&max_sitelink_count=&cb_labels_no_l=1&max_age=&referrer_url=&after=&search_max_results=500&subpage_filter=either&sparql=&categories=360%C2%B0%20panoramas%0D%0AStreets&langs_labels_any=&doit=) may be better at finding category intersections.